# Intermittent NaN and INF Values on ESP32

Tags: nan, esp32, arduino-esp32, inf

I am developing some PID code for an ESP32 dev module. Most times that I execute the code, the `integral` value is NaN or INF. However, upon unplugging and replugging in the USB connection, occasionally the integral value will calculate as expected. I have tested across multiple different types of dev kits and observed the same behavior, which leads me to believe this is a software bug.

What could be the cause of this error? What more troubleshooting steps would you recommend?

```
//==============Variables================
// Frequency Counter
const byte        interruptPin = 22;              // Assign the interrupt pin
volatile uint64_t StartValue = 0;                 // First interrupt value
volatile uint64_t PeriodCount;                    // period in counts
float             freq;                           // frequency

hw_timer_t * timer = NULL;                        // pointer to a variable of type hw_timer_t

// PID
const int OUTPUT_PIN = 23;

double dt = 0.1;
double last_time = 0;
double integral = 0;
double previous = 0;
double output = 75;
double kp, ki, kd;
double setpoint = 35.00;                          // idle speed of ~35 Hz

//==============Functions================
// Interrupt
void IRAM_ATTR handleInterrupt()
{
  uint64_t TempVal = timerRead(timer);            // value of timer at interrupt
  PeriodCount = TempVal - StartValue;             // period count between rising edges
  StartValue = TempVal;                           // puts latest reading as start for next calculation
}

// PID Function
double pid(double error)
{
  double proportional = error;
  double area = error * dt;
  integral += area;                               // issue found: integral = inf or nan
  double derivative = (error - previous) / dt;
  previous = error;
  double output = (kp * proportional) + (ki * integral) + (kd * derivative);
  Serial.print("integral: ");
  Serial.println(integral, 6);
}
//=======================================

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);                                       // sets pin as input
  
  attachInterrupt(interruptPin, handleInterrupt, FALLING);            // attaches pin to interrupt on Falling Edge
  timer = timerBegin(0, 2, true);                                     // configure timer 
  // 0 = first timer
  // 2 is prescaler so 80 MHZ divided by 2 = 40 MHZ signal
  // true - counts up
  timerStart(timer);                                                  // starts the timer

//=======================================
  // PID setup
  kp = 0.8;
  ki = 0.5;
  kd = 0;
  last_time = 0;
  analogWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, 23);
}
  
void loop(){
  freq = 40000000.00 / ((double) PeriodCount);                       // calculate frequency 

//=======================================
  // PID Loop
  double now = millis();
  dt = (now - last_time) / ((double) 1000);
  last_time = now;
  delay(1);
  
  double error = freq - setpoint;
  output = pid(error);                                              // output is the PWM value

  analogWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, output);                                  // set the output pin to the PWM value determined by the output variable
}
```

Comment: How often does the PID loop run? Does it ever run twice in the same millisecond? It doesn't look like it should with delay(1), but it might be worth delay(100) just to see, since dt=0 might cause INF in pid(). Same also with PeriodCount - is it ever zero(if IRQ happens twice per timer tick)?

Comment: You really need to declare `PeriodCount` as `volatile`. Any variables that you use both inside an interrupt handler and in code that might be interrupted need to be `volatile` so that the compiler will know their values may change unpredictably and avoid certain optimizations that will fail if code using the variable is interrupted during its use. Also is there a reason you're doing this instead of just using an existing PID library that works already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll point out a few easily spotted issues.

1. This statement does not account for cases where `PeriodCount` is 0. That's how you get an Inf :)
   `freq = 40000000.00 / ((double) PeriodCount);`
2. All your variables are 8 bytes in length (double and uint64_t). You cannot safely share those between an interrupt and task loop on a 4 byte architecture. That's because the interrupt can drop in and change value between the main loop handling the first and second 4-byte half of the variable. As a result the main loop's computation runs on a thrashed value. That's how you get a NaN.
   The solution is to protect them with a mutex or other thread synchronization mechanism.
3. Repeating the comment by romkey - variables shared between main and interrupt *must* be volatile, or the compiler will take its liberty with them.